# Django upload FileField and ImageField in differnt servers

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I want to make a system where user can upload document files and also images *(both for different tasks)*

and i want to store the files in my own ftp server and images in s3 bucket.

i am using `django-storages` package

never saw a django approach like this, where `FileField` and `ImageField`s can be uploaded to different servers

for example, let's say when user uploads a file the file gets uploaded to my ftp server

```
FTP_USER = 'testuser'#os.environ['FTP_USER']
FTP_PASS = 'testpassword'#os.environ['FTP_PASS']
FTP_PORT = '21'#os.environ['FTP_PORT']
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.ftp.FTPStorage'
FTP_STORAGE_LOCATION = 'ftp://' + FTP_USER + ':' + FTP_PASS + '@192.168.0.200:' + FTP_PORT




# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_my_proj"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_cdn", "static_root")


MEDIA_URL = 'ftp://192.168.0.200/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'ftp://192.168.0.200/'#os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_cdn", "media_root")
```

*but problem is images now goto ftp server also*

**because of this**

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.ftp.FTPStorage'
```

**yeah i know i can make different directories inside uploaded server root directory like this**

```
def get_filename_ext(filepath):
    base_name = os.path.basename(filepath)
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(base_name)
    return name, ext


def upload_image_path(instance, filename):
    # print(instance)
    #print(filename)
    new_filename = random.randint(1,3910209312)
    name, ext = get_filename_ext(filename)
    final_filename = '{new_filename}{ext}'.format(new_filename=new_filename, ext=ext)
    return "myapp/{new_filename}/{final_filename}".format(
            new_filename=new_filename, 
            final_filename=final_filename
            )

class Product(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug            = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    document        = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return "/products/{slug}/".format(slug=self.slug)
        return reverse("detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**but that's not what i want, i want different servers for file and image uploads**

is that even possible ? i mean there can be only one `MEDIA_ROOT` so how can i write *two server addresses*, am i making sense ?

**EDIT 1:**

[iain shelvington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548562/iain-shelvington) mentioned a great point, that to add storage option for each field for customized storage backend

like this

```
from storages.backends.ftp import FTPStorage
fs = FTPStorage()

class FTPTest(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='srv/ftp/', storage=fs)

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
```

and in settings this

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.ftp.FTPStorage'
FTP_STORAGE_LOCATION = 'ftp://user:password@localhost:21
```

but user uploaded photos also gets uploaded to that ftp server
due tp

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.ftp.FTPStorage'
```

and about the `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT`  they can be only one right ?
so how can i put two different server address there ?

Thanks for reading this, i really appreciate it.

Comment: You can pass `storage` to a `FileField` to customise the storage backend used for each field https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage

Comment: hello many thanks for commenting i edited the question according to your comment, please take a look when you have time , thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a **`base_url`** in the **`FTPStorage`** class as

```
from storages.backends.ftp import FTPStorage
from django.conf import settings

fs = FTPStorage(base_url=settings.FTP_STORAGE_LOCATION)


class FTPTest(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='srv/ftp/', storage=fs)


class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
```

This `base_url` is useful in ***building the "absolute URL" of the file*** and hence you don't need *`MEDIA_URL`* and *`MEDIA_ROOT`* *"in this case"*

---

> I want different servers for file and image uploads.

You can achieve it by specifying the **`storage`** parameter the `FileField` (or `ImageField`)

> but user uploaded photos also gets uploaded to that ftp server due to, `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` settings.

It is your choice. What should be the *default storage class in your case*? Do you need to upload the media files to S3? or local storage, where the project runs? set the value accordingly.

Comment: so in django media_url and media_root is default url and location the user uploaded files goes to.. which we can change to a custom one on top of the default one (default stays same) with the storage parameter and base_url... amazing !!